# Having Trouble with Repeating Images

Tags: css, html

Working on a site that is just HTML and CSS. I am quite new with this. I have a header, body and footer that I would like to repeat to fill up the page. Think [envato.com](http://envato.com).

Here is some sample code I have so far.

CSS:

```
.blkside {
z-index:99;
background-image: url(/images/blkside.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
top:0px;
right:85px;
position: absolute;
}
```

the corresponding HTML:

```
<div class="blkside"><img src="/images/blkside.jpg"></div>
```

This is just one of the divs that I have. 3 repeat horizontally, and 1 repeats vertically. From my searching, this all looks correct code wise, but does not show up right. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

simple example below.

```
<div class="repeat"></div>

.repeat {
    background:url(/images/blkside.jpg) top left repeat-x;
    height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set measurements on the div (height/width) and once you define the image in the css you do not need to put it in the html as well

Answer (score 0):

The code to repeat an image on the whole page background is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>this is the title of the web page</title>

<style type="text/css">

body
{
background-image:
url(full link to your image goes here);
background-repeat: repeat-xy;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```